# Rename a file from the raw_input

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, raw-input

I am quite new to python in general and I am creating a small script that takes the input from a user and exports that data into a .txt, however I would like the exported file to be auto renamed based upon on of the inputs from the user.

```
firstname = raw_input("What is your First Name?" + "\n")
print 'Thank you, %s' % firstname ,

lastname = raw_input("What is your last name?" + "\n")
print 'Thank you %s' % firstname ,'%s' % lastname

age = raw_input("How old are you?" + "\n")
print 'Thank you %s' % firstname , '%s' % lastname

postcode = raw_input("What is your postal code?" + "\n")
print 'Thank you %s' % firstname , '%s' % lastname

jobtitle = raw_input("What is your current Job Title?" + "\n")
print 'Thank you %s' % firstname , '%s' % lastname

file = open("/Users/AshleyRedman/Desktop/Users [CUS] Py27/userinfo.txt", "w")

file.write(firstname +",")
file.write(lastname +",")
file.write(age +",")
file.write(postcode +",")
file.write(jobtitle)

file.close()
```

After this, how / what is the best way to take the 'firstname' and 'lastname' and rename the file 'user info.txt' to that?

Comment: Why do you want to *rename* the file? Why don't you just create it with that name, i.e. change the line `file = open(...)` - you already know `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jonrsharpe gave you a good answer in the comments, but I thought I'd also give you some ideas since it looks like you are just trying to learn new things...

You can also do open("test.txt", "a") if you just want to open the file up to append data to it.

Also you might like to look at using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.  It can handle parsing csv files for you.

```
import csv
....
with open('userinfo.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter= csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # write the csv header
    csvwriter.writerow('firstname', 'lastname', 'age', 'postcode', 'jobtitle')
    # write the data row (often a loop here writing rows of data)
    csvwriter.writerow([firstname, lastname, age, postcode, jobtitle])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your right, at the moment I'm just throwing together a few ideas and to try new things, I did look into the csv module, but as I have just started off, I couldn't quite understand it as much as I should, though for this purpose I will revisit it :)

Comment: I added an example of using the csv module for you.  Have fun!

Comment: Thank you! Would this be a possible way to create one .csv file that can be constantly update with different 'answers' so using those headers and the data in the columns below?

Comment: @AshleyRedman Yep, just open it with 'ab' mode.  You also wouldn't want to rewrite the header of course. So perhaps do something like check if the file exists, if it does not, open it 'wb' and write the header, otherwise open it 'ab'.  Then just write the rows like normal.